# Is there any documents about ${command:...} in launch.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using `${command:pickProcess}` to [debug a running process](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_additional-properties) and I've seen a [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/pipe-transport) about using `${command:pickRemoteProcess}` with the pipeTransPort.

What I want to know is the documentation for all `${command:*}`. The [variable reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_command-variables) says almost nothing.

I found [Built-in Commands reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands), but it seems unrelated to this. Also searching for "pickProcess" in the repository didn't help either. Search result is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/search?q=pickProcess%20in%3Afile).

Is there any reference for this? The relevant source code location is also fine.

Comment: any command you can find in the key bind GUI can be used, for some commands it is a guessing game what the arguments are

Comment: these 2 commands are not mentioned in the key bind GUI, and I can't find `pickProcess` in the source code, apart from `${action.pickProcess}` in a literal string for i18n. Curious how it is handled in the code because somehow it works.

Comment: @rioV8 I tried `${command:cmake.build}` for processId in launch.json. It start build and it claims 'cmake.build' did not return a string. This is what I expected. Maybe I can use some other command which return a string.

Comment: Now I think those two commands are kind of special reserved commands.

Comment: yes but these strings (command names) have to detected somehow, but they are not mentioned literal in the source code